# Turn off Google Instant with a URL parameter

Tags: google-search

Is there a URL parameter to turn off [Google Instant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search#Instant_Search)?

Google Instant overrides other URL parameters. This affects Firefox toolbar search users and anyone who uses bookmarks or favorites with custom parameters. Turning it off through Preferences is a hassle and only lasts until your cookies are cleared. If there isn't a parameter to turn off Google Instant, there needs to be.

Answer (score 4):

The following will turn it off and will also work if the browser is set to *clear cookies upon exit*, according to Google's support page:

```
http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=0&hl=en
```

<sub>Source: BTCreative's answer in *[Google Instant is horrible. I can't turn it off. The vast majority seem to agree. Google - STOP adding this stuff!!](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/websearch/HztEUQwD5yE/p9MWPyDwc0kJ)* .</sub>

Comment: The link you provided is giving a 404 error.

Comment: In this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/59867/29140, the `complete=0` is used to disable the auto complete. The `ion=0` is used to disable the `instant` search. Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can disable Google Instant without disabling Autocomplete:

https://www.google.com?ion=0

Subsequent searches on the results page will have Google Instant again, though.

Answer (score 1):

[GeneQ's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6809/turn-off-google-instant-with-a-url-parameter/7782#7782) is the direct answer to the question, but an alternative to get the desired effect wrt. turning off Google Instant, even when cookies are cleared upon exit, is to change the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) (HTTP header field `User-Agent`) the browser sends. Note that this may or may not have undesired side effects on things that depends on it (for example, some JavaScript code).

1. In [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox): [change `general.useragent.override`](https://superuser.com/questions/103798/how-can-i-anonymize-my-browser-useragent-yet-still-be-counted-as-a-ff-ubuntu-use/302081#302081) to something like `googleinstantisreallyirritating` or `www.google.com`.
2. In [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29): apparently [it is not possible](https://superuser.com/questions/302102/switching-user-agent-in-opera/302157#302157).
3. In [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome): [hack the Chrome.dll file](http://www.labnol.org/software/change-google-chrome-user-agent-string/4566/) (Windows only?).
4. In [Internet Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer): TBD.

Answer (score 0):

https://encrypted.google.com seems to be an easy way to disable it!

Comment: Obviously you could just disable it in your search settings.

Comment: Yes, but he was specific about a URL parameter. I beleive he wanted to shift back and forth

Comment: Yes, I get that. Your solution isn't an URL parameter either; it's a separate URL.

Comment: Yup...but it serves his purpose better I presume :)

Answer (score 0):

This URL will disable Google Instant. You can also set the number of search results you want per page, and the search results will open in a new window:

https://www.google.com/webhp?num=20&newwindow=1&complete=0&hl=en

Just change `num=20` to the number of search results per page you would like.

Answer (score 0):

No need - [Instant](https://www.theverge.com/2017/7/26/16034844/google-kills-off-instant-search-for-mobile-consistency) has been discontinued.

Answer (score -3):

In 'search setting' panel, there is an option for Google Instant, turn off this option to disable Instant search.

Comment: OP wanted a URL solution.